# maybeStripe.apply is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments, es6-promise

Ahoy,

Getting an error with Stripe in Gatsby occurs on page load

*Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: maybeStripe.apply is not a function*

```
    import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
    import { loadStripe } from '@stripe/stripe-js';
    import { Elements } from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';
    import StripeCheckout from './stripeCheckout'
    
    const stripePromise = loadStripe('pk_test_xyz');
    
    function App() {
        const [clientSecret, setClientSecret] = useState('');
    
        useEffect(() => {
            fetch("/.netlify/functions/createIntent")
                .then((res) => res.json())
                .then(({ clientSecret }) => setClientSecret(clientSecret));
        }, [])
    
        const options = {
            clientSecret,
        }
    
        return (
            <main>
                <h1>Payment</h1>
                {clientSecret && (
                    <Elements stripe={stripePromise} options={options}>
                        <StripeCheckout />
                    </Elements>
                )}
            </main>
        );
    }
    
    export default App;
```

```
    import {
        PaymentElement
      } from '@stripe/react-stripe-js'
      import React, {useState} from 'react'
      import {useStripe, useElements} from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';
      
      export default function CheckoutForm() {
        const stripe = useStripe();
        const elements = useElements();
        const [message, setMessage] = useState(null);
        const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
      
        const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
      
          if (!stripe || !elements) {
            return;
          }
      
          setIsLoading(true);
      
          const { error } = await stripe.confirmPayment({
            elements,
            confirmParams: {
              // Make sure to change this to your payment completion page
              return_url: "http://localhost:8888",
            },
          });
      
          if (error.type === "card_error" || error.type === "validation_error") {
            setMessage(error.message);
          } else {
            setMessage("An unexpected error occured.");
          }
      
          setIsLoading(false);
        }
      
        return (
          <form id="payment-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <PaymentElement id="payment-element" />
            <button disabled={isLoading || !stripe || !elements} id="submit">
              <span id="button-text">
                {isLoading ? <div className="spinner" id="spinner"></div> : "Pay now"}
              </span>
            </button>
            {message && <div id="payment-message">{message}</div>}
          </form>
        )
      }
```

Can't seem to find any ref's to this issue on here or stripes documentation, not sure if this is a Gatsby issue or I am just doing something wrong.

Any help is greatly appreciated

cheers

Comment: Where in your code is that error uncaught?

Comment: Hi Jonathan, 

Error in function initStripe in ./node_modules/@stripe/stripe-js/dist/stripe.esm.js:101

   99 |   }
  100 |
> 101 |   var stripe = maybeStripe.apply(undefined, args);
  102 |   registerWrapper(stripe, startTime);
  103 |   return stripe;
  104 | };

Please let me know if that helps. 

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds potentially like Stripe.js isn't being initialised properly for whatever reason. [This](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-js/issues/253) issue sounds somewhat similar. Perhaps try using the alternative 'pure' import which will [defer loading](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-js#importing-loadstripe-without-side-effects) Stripe.js until you call `loadStripe`. Otherwise I'd suggest filing an issue over on GitHub!

Comment: Hi Jonathan, thanks for your help. I ended up removing node_modules and added the /pure. and everything is working now. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Removed node_modules and reinstalled and added import { loadStripe } from '@stripe/stripe-js/pure';

Answer (score 0):

You may have installed other modules like @stripe/stripe-js but I don't think you installed the main stripe module. So run `npm i stripe` or `yarn add stripe` and the error will be fixed

Answer (score 0):

In my case, PUBLIC_KEY was undefined when passed to loadStripe(PUBLIC_KEY).
Once the appropriate PUBLIC_KEY was provided the issue was resolved

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).